# Add a single query result to a List

Tags: c#, linq

I need to be able to search for a single name out of an ASP.NET `DropDownList`, then add the `player` with that name to a list.

My query looks like this:

```
List<Player> players = new List<Player>();
var p1 = from p in db.Players
         where p.PlayerName == DropDownListPlayer1.SelectedItem.Text
         select p;
```

Then, I somehow need to add this result to the list, but

```
players.Add(p1);
```

gives me two errors:

> Cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'Player,'

And:

> the best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List.Add(Player)' has some invalid
>   arguments.

I've tried having the query select a new instance of Player instead:

```
var p1 = from p in db.Players
         where p.PlayerName == DropDownListPlayer1.SelectedItem.Text
         select new Player {PlayerName = p.PlayerName,
                            PlayerId = p.PlayerId};
```

As well as sending the results to a list, and adding the first (and only) player in the list to the new list, all to no avail.

Comment: Is this windows or web sir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a single name, but `Select` returns a sequence (`IQueryable<Player>`), you should call `First` or `Single` on the query before adding to the result list:

```
var p1 = (from p in db.Players
         where p.PlayerName == DropDownListPlayer1.SelectedItem.Text
         select p).First();

players.Add(p1);
```

Comment: This approach solves my initial errors, but running the code causes a EntityCommandExecutionException. Im trying to wrap my head around what this error means, contextually, but its all a bit over my head.

Comment: hmm..entitycommandexecutionexception? what does the InnerException says?

Comment: @kenlacoste After learning what The innerException IS, it says that I have invalid column names for columns that no longer exist. I forgot to update the entity model. Dont I feel silly.

Comment: nice..that at least completes your quest. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your query returns multiple results, but method `Add` expects just a single result. Instead you can use function `AddRange` to add multiple results:

```
players.AddRange(p1.ToList());
```

I am also calling `ToList` to immetiately execute query on the database.

If the list `players` is empty when you try to execute the above code, even better approach is to use the method `ToList()` to create the list:

```
List<Player> players = (from p in db.Players
     where p.PlayerName == DropDownListPlayer1.SelectedItem.Text
     select p).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var p1 = (from p in db.Players
                 where p.PlayerName == DropDownListPlayer1.SelectedItem.Text
                 select new Player {PlayerName = p.PlayerName,
                                    PlayerId = p.PlayerId}
         ).FirstOrDefault();

if(p1 != null)
{
     players.Add(p1);
}
```